# Get Value From JSON using JSONPath returning null

Tags: python, python-3.x, rest, automated-tests, robotframework

Newbie here: I'm trying to get the id from the response body of a POST call. POST is successful but when I try to get the id and log it, it returns null. I think I'm simply missing a minor thing but yeah, need your help.

```
  ${response_body}    Decode Bytes To String    ${response.content}    encoding=utf-8     
  Set Test Variable    ${response_body}     
  Log    ${response_body}     
  ${id}    Get Value From Json    ${response_body}    id     
  Log    ${id}
```

Actual Response body is just:

```
    {
        "id": "546e0c4d-b810-49e6-a674-0d0f812bb790"
    }
```

Here is what I get in the reports:

[report that shows id is empty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFlAK.png)

No errors, just blank value

I tried setting the response_body as the id as a whole but I get "id"="xxxxx..." when I call the ${id} so yeah I just need the value

Comment: I dont think the response_bordy is parsed as a proper json. You might want to check that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `${response_body}` is a string, not a JSON. You must use `Convert String To Json` to convert it to JSON before `Get Value From Json` works.